# How to group by name, date and limit the current_date

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am making a chatbot where people can send his report in one android game, so i created a php page where you can see the report of the day based on a mysql query. But i can't create the correct query. This is what i have tried:

```
select
    id, nickname, fecha, bestia1, bestia2, bestia3, bestia4, bestia5
from
    reporte
where
    fecha > CURRENT_DATE()
group by
    nickname DESC
```

As you can see, my table "reporte" saves the information sent by a character, but one character can send many reports per day, so i want to show only the latest report per name.

I need to group by nickname, order by date, and get the latest report for each nickname, but i have problems with that. I have seen many similar posts but still can't figure out exactly what i have to do. I need some help, thanks!

[my actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDNFR.png) [my select from order by date. but i want to show the latest per nickname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9chx.png)

Comment: Consider revising your schema. See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to query table **reporte** for get the **fecha** of the latest register for every **nickname**, like this:

**Spanish translation:**

Primero, debes consultar la tabla **reporte** para obtener la **fecha** correspondiente al último registro de cada nickname:

```
SELECT nickname, MAX(fecha)
FROM reporte
GROUP BY nickname
```

Now, i will show you how to join this previous query for get the rest of the data related to the latest report associated with each **nickname**:

**Spanish translation:**

Ahora, te mostraré cómo realizar un join con esta consulta previa para obtener el resto de los datos relacionados con el último informe de cada **nickname**:

```
SELECT
    r1.id,
    r1.nickname,
    r1.fecha,
    r1.bestia1,
    r1.bestia2,
    r1.bestia3,
    r1.bestia4,
    r1.bestia5
FROM
    reporte AS r1
INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT nickname, MAX(fecha) AS max_date
      FROM reporte
      GROUP BY nickname
      HAVING MAX(fecha) >= CURRENT_DATE()
    ) AS latests_reports ON latests_reports.nickname = r1.nickname AND latests_reports.max_date = r1.fecha
```

Comment: thanks for the good code friend, i tested it and i am having the message "
The column 'latest_reports.max_date' in on clause is unknown"

Comment: It was just a typing error, i have fixed it now, it should be `latests_reports.max_date`

Comment: thanks!, i got this code starting from your code "SELECT r1.id, r1.nickname, r1.fecha, r1.bestia1, r1.bestia2, r1.bestia3, r1.bestia4, r1.bestia5 FROM reporte AS r1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT nickname, MAX(fecha) AS max_date FROM reporte GROUP BY nickname ) AS latests_reports ON latests_reports.nickname = r1.nickname AND latests_reports.max_date = r1.fecha ORDER BY `r1`.`fecha` DESC" it looks good, but do you know how to add my line "WHERE fecha>CURRENT_DATE()"? i am finishing with that friend, thanks, thats because the current query shows all the rows per each day, and i want show only the current

Comment: The query i made for you (if i'm not wrong), will show the last report associated with each nickname. If you want to ignore reports before certain date, then use WHERE clause at the end of the query or in the inner query, i will update with this feature (using inner query filtering).

Comment: ohh, thats the best guide about mysql and group with date limits friend, thanks!

Comment: It works?, if so, you can help me voting up and marking my answer as the correct one. I will appreciate it.

Comment: Sir please can you teach me how to count values per nickname wich has already in groups i want to learn how to do an score

Comment: @G.Romero Sure, but made a question describing your problem, the schema of the tables and what you have tried so far, including sample data and expected output will improve your question too. After that, just put the link fo your new question here and I will check it. But, i'm sure there will be lot of people that can help to resolve your problem.

Comment: wow thanks for your help, just i want to count correctly the monsters killed per day in order to show in google data studio or highcharts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438107/create-a-ranking-and-statistics-with-repeated-database-records

Comment: sir srry for that, this is my last question about that, ¿how can i use delete from to clean repeated tables from the same day? i mean delete from the table except the latest report havin max(fecha) group by nickname

Answer (score 0):

You've missed out on the `order by` part of your query.

Assuming the rest is correct, here's your query:

```
select id,nickname, fecha,bestia1,bestia2,bestia3,bestia4,bestia5 from reporte WHERE fecha>CURRENT_DATE() group by nickname order by id DESC
```

As there's a group by, you may need to change `id` to `max(id)`

Comment: thanks friend, i checked this and it shows the old information from each nickname, where i uploaded my report with 0/0/0 values and the latest in the same nickname is 3/0/0, so it shows 0/0/0/ ignoring the latest report