# create a ranking and statistics with repeated database records

Tags: mysql, sql, highcharts, ranking

Today I want to get a help in creating scores per user in my database. I have this query:

```
SELECT
    r1.id,
    r1.nickname,
    r1.fecha,
    r1.bestia1,
    r1.bestia2,
    r1.bestia3,
    r1.bestia4
    r1.bestia5
FROM
    reporte AS r1
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT
          nickname, MAX(fecha) AS max_date
      FROM
          reporte
      GROUP BY
          nickname ) AS latests_reports 
ON latests_reports.nickname = r1.nickname
AND latests_reports.max_date = r1.fecha
ORDER BY
    r1.fecha DESC
```

that's from a friend from this site who helped me in get "the last record per user in each day", based on this I am looking how to count the results in a ranking daily, weekly or monthly, in order to use statistics charts or google datastudio, I've tried the next:

```
select id, nickname, sum(bestia1), sum(bestia2), etc...
```

But its not giving the complete result which I want. That's why I am looking for help. Additionally I know datastudio filters where I can show many charts but still I can count completely.

for example, one player in the last 30 days reported 265 monsters killed, but when I use in datastudio my query it counts only the latest value (it can be 12). so I want to count correctly in order to use with charts

SQL records filtered with my query:

[image]

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing. Consider revising your schema

Comment: Just to clarify and like a starting point, do you need to group by user (column `nickname`) and then get the sum of monster (column `bestia1` + column `bestia2` + column `bestia3` + column `bestia4` + column `bestia5`) they killed on some day (maybe the current one)? Then, later, do you need this same calculation but over the last week and month?. Also if you can add add some sample of data, and the output you expect to get from they, that will help a lot.

Comment: yes, i need to put in a report who killed more monsters in the current week, the last week or last month, additionally i was thinking in something like that sum(bestia1*1),sum(bestia2*2) in order to create an "score" where each monster is counting for ranking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general approach for get the total monsters killed by each user on the **latest X days** and make a score calculation like the one you propose on the commentaries can be like this:

```
SET @daysOnHistory = X; -- Where X should be an integer positive number (like 10).

SELECT
    nickname,
    SUM(bestia1) AS total_bestia1_killed,
    SUM(bestia2) AS total_bestia2_killed,
    SUM(bestia3) AS total_bestia3_killed,
    SUM(bestia4) AS total_bestia4_killed,
    SUM(bestia5) AS total_bestia5_killed,
    SUM(bestia1 + bestia2 + bestia3 + bestia4 + bestia5) AS total_monsters_killed,
    SUM(bestia1 +  2 * bestia2 + 3 * bestia3 + 4 * bestia4 + 5 * bestia5) AS total_score
FROM
    reporte
WHERE
    fecha >= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -@daysOnHistory DAY)
GROUP BY
    nickname
ORDER BY
    total_score DESC
```

Now, if you want the same calculation but only taking into account the **days of the current week** (assuming a week starts on Monday), you need to replace the previous `WHERE` clause by next one:

```
WHERE
    fecha >= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY)
```

Even more, if you want all the same, but only taking into account the **days of the current month**, you need to replace the `WHERE` clause by:

```
WHERE
    MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(NOW())
```

For evaluate the statistics on the **days of the current year**, you need to replace the `WHERE` clause by:

```
WHERE
    YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(NOW())
```

And finally, for evaluation on a **specific range of days** you can use, for example:

```
WHERE
    DATE(fecha) BETWEEN CAST("2018-10-15" AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-11-10' AS DATE)
```

I hope this guide will help you and clarify your outlook.

Comment: sir, how can i get the report from yesterday or x days ago? but only from these day?  because i tried tu put the exact date or range of days but it sums all monsters

Comment: Check the first query of my guide, but change `where` clause by `DATE(fecha) = DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -@daysOnHistory DAY )`.

Comment: Hello sir, the ranking for current week is bot working properly, i created a ranking in PHP and today i AM not getting any data

Comment: @G.Romero I have updated my answer. Use this for week ranking: `WHERE fecha >= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY)`. Tellme if it works as you expect now... Also, if you could vote me up, i will appeciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you number of monster killed in the last 30 days per user :

```
SELECT
    nickname,
    sum(bestia1) as bestia1,
    sum(bestia2) as bestia2,
    sum(bestia3) as bestia3,
    sum(bestia4) as bestia4,
    sum(bestia5) as bestia5
FROM
    reporte 
WHERE   fecha >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), interval -30 day)
GROUP BY nickName
ORDER BY
```

Comment: thankyou for that sir, i am working with this code just now in order to replace interval days per current week or last week, for example i want to get the monster killed per user this week from 19/11 to 25/11, if you know that please explain to me... thanks

Comment: For monster killed between 19 to 25, replace where clause for `WHERE fecha between '2018-11-19' and '2018-11-25 23:59:59'`  If you omit 23:59:59, you will be missing entries of the last day in the range.  `between '2018-11-19' and '2018-11-25'` will be from 11-19 midnight to 11-25 midnight (night between 24 and 25).